# CSS Bottom Padding page stops scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

I am developing a mobile app using PhoneGap build - so using HTML/CSS/JS

My app works fine on android and iphones, however it scaled wrong on iPad which caused it to be rejected from the store.

To restore the correct aspect ratio to fix the scaling, I added the following code:

```
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
    for(var i = 0; i < body .length; i++)
    {
        body [i].style.paddingTop = "56.25%";
    }
```

This works exactly as intended, however:

When I scroll to the bottom of a page now it will suddenly stop at the start of the bottom padding.

Then, I have to scroll again to reach the bottom of the page, as if scrolling a different element. Then when I scroll back up, the same thing happens the same distance from the top.

Using the element inspector in chrome I can see that the padding I have set is the issue.

here is my html tag that I am manipulating once I detect the device is an iPad:

```
html 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: var(--royalpaleblue);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    font-family: Ubuntu, "times new roman", times, roman, serif;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    /* Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    /* Konqueror HTML */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;
    /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none;
    /* Non-prefixed version, currently supported by Chrome and Opera */

    overflow-y: scroll !important; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;

    padding-bottom: 0%;
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, and I can't find anything on the web, so is there a way to have scrolling ignore padding and continue to the bottom of the page?